# Cypress-тестирование: можно ли запускать тесты каждый раз при включении компьютера?

Tags: javascript, node.js, тестирование, автоматизация

Есть такая библиотека для тестирования Cypress, можно ли настроить так, чтобы определенная цепочка тестов запускалась каждый раз при включении компьютера? Как этой сделать? Не смог понять по документации к самой библиотеке...

Comment: Если вы тест сможете запустить из командной строки, то вам надо повесить задание в автозагрузку вашего ПК, создать батник(cmd, sh - в зависимости от ОС). И пусть при старте вашей ОС он вызывается. Сама библиотека это не сделает, как мне видится...

Comment: спасибо, самый разумный вариант. похоже...